# Ember.js stringtoclass

Tags: javascript, object, ember.js, objectinstantiation

I'm searching a way to instatiate a new ember object with the classname as a string:

```
App.MyObject = Ember.Object.extend({hello:'hello'});
//Try to do something like this.
App.myObject = Ember.create("App.MyObject", {hello:'Hello World!'});
console.log(App.myObject.hello); //productes 'Hello World!'
```

Is there a possibility to do something like this?

Comment: Found out that "Ember.get" does exactly what I want:     Ember.get(window, "App.MyObject").create({hello:'Hello World!'});

Comment: Please close the question if you have found the answer.

Comment: Hi, how do I close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont need to use getters and setters in your special case.

Your solution was

```
Ember.get(window, "App.MyObject").create({hello:'Hello World!'});
```

But I think a simple one like:

```
var className = "MyObject";
App[className].create({hello:'Hello World!'});
```

will work.